# Using the data validation function

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-validation

Is there a way when using the data validation function on a list that includes blanks to have the blanks not shown in the drop down menu??

Answer (score 1):

Use a formula that consolidates the range with blanks to a range without blanks, then source the data validation from that. Worksheet space is cheap, so be prepared to use helper columns to do what you need to do.

The formula in cell B1 of the screenshot (copied down) is

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$10,SMALL(IF(ISTEXT($A$2:$A$10),ROW($A$1:$A$9),""),ROW(A1))),"")
```

If you want to understand how and why it works, visit https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/excel-remove-blank-cells-from-a-range

[image]